# How can you display a national field in cobol?

Tags: cobol

I like to put displays in my test drivers for programs I wrote, to see what's going on. In my case I'm working with a copybook that contains PIC N fields. 
I would like to display the following field:  `05 MESSAGE-TEXT PIC N(20).`

A normal  `DISPLAY MESSAGE-TEXT IN COPYBOOK` makes it impossible for me to read. Do I have to define a new field, for example PIC-X-FIELD, use a  `MOVE FUNCTION DISPLAY-OF ( MESSAGE-TEXT IN COPYBOOK ) TO PIC-X-FIELD` and then do a display of that PIC-X-FIELD? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Haha yes, sorry, I should have clarified: I cannot read it and when I turn on hex it shows a lot of gibberish. I'm using IN to specify the fields used in the copybook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gibberish you see when you look at a National (PIC N) field in hexadecimal on your output is the hexadecimal value of that national field. It is the UTF-8 value of that field. For "ordinary" characters, that will be one byte of binary zeros, followed by the "ASCII" code for the character.

The capital letter "A", for instance, will be X'0041'.

When using National fields, you mostly don't have to use the FUNCTION NATIONAL-OF to make the conversion. For instance, for a simple MOVE of a PIC X to a PIC N the compiler knows what you want, and generates the code you need to effect the conversion.

One place where the conversion is not automatic is... `DISPLAY`.

However, what you can do in a DISPLAY is use the FUNCTION DISPLAY-OF ( ... ) to get your output.

Here's a short program that illustrates the above (and also shows another use of a, reference-modified, FUNCTION with DISPLAY):

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  W-WHEN-COMPILED                     PIC X(8)BX(8). 
   01  A-NATIONAL                          PIC N(1) VALUE "A".
   01  A-DISPLAY                           PIC X VALUE "?". 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       MOVE WHEN-COMPILED           TO W-WHEN-COMPILED 
       DISPLAY "PROGRAM-NAME COMPILED ON " W-WHEN-COMPILED 

       DISPLAY 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED 
       DISPLAY 
               "DATE COMPILED (YYYY-MM-DD): " 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 1 : 4 ) 
               "-" 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 5 : 2 ) 
               "-" 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 7 : 2 ) 
               " TIME: " 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 9 : 2 ) 
               ":" 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 11 : 2 ) 
               ":" 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 13 : 2 ) 
               " OFFSET TO GMT:" 
               FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED ( 17 : 5 ) 
       PERFORM                      DO-THE-DISPLAYS 

       ACCEPT A-DISPLAY 
       MOVE A-DISPLAY               TO A-NATIONAL 
       PERFORM                      DO-THE-DISPLAYS 
       ACCEPT A-DISPLAY 
       MOVE FUNCTION NATIONAL-OF 
             ( A-DISPLAY )          TO A-NATIONAL 
       PERFORM                      DO-THE-DISPLAYS 


       GOBACK 
       . 
   DO-THE-DISPLAYS. 
       DISPLAY 
              "THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>" 
               A-NATIONAL 
              "<" 
       DISPLAY 
              "THE DISPLAY, NATIVE >" 
               A-DISPLAY 
              "<" 
       DISPLAY 
              "THE DISPLAY-OF FUNC >" 
              FUNCTION DISPLAY-OF 
                ( A-NATIONAL ) 
              "<" 
       .
```

Some JCL to run it:

```
//stepname EXEC PGM=program,TIME=(,2) nice to limit things always
//STEPLIB DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your executable library
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN DD * 
C 
D
```

The output is:

```
04/13/16 09.28.21                                                        
2016041309282183+0000                                                    
DATE COMPILED (YYYY-MM-DD): 2016-04-13 TIME: 09:28:21 OFFSET TO GMT:+0000
THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>  <                                                 
THE DISPLAY, NATIVE >?<                                                  
THE DISPLAY-OF FUNC >A<                                                  
THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>  <                                                 
THE DISPLAY, NATIVE >C<                                                  
THE DISPLAY-OF FUNC >C<                                                  
THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>  <                                                 
THE DISPLAY, NATIVE >D<                                                  
THE DISPLAY-OF FUNC >D<
```

In hex for the National  :

```
THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>  <
ECC4DCECDDCD64DCECEC6044
385051396513B0513955E01C
 -----------------------
THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>  <
ECC4DCECDDCD64DCECEC6044
385051396513B0513955E03C
 -----------------------
THE NATIONAL, NATIVE>  <
ECC4DCECDDCD64DCECEC6044
385051396513B0513955E04C
```

Note, your output for FUNCTION WHEN-COMPILED may be different, I have never used it with COBOL for OS/390 and VM. Also the format of the date may be different, an installation option.

Also not that FUNCTION DISPLAY-OF (and NATIONAL-OF) can take, as a second argument, a Code Page. If you happened to require National with a different Code Page than the default (and were not able to/didn't want to specify the Code Page as a compiler option, or required multiple Code Page output in the same program) you can specify the Code Page in the functions to get the correct output. In these types of cases, you could not use the default conversion for MOVE etc, but would have to explicitly convert via the functions.